# A member of the type, 'Method', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Hello I am getting an error on that reads

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified
>   'TestSearch_Result'. A member of the
>   type, 'Method', does not have a corresponding column in the data
>   reader with the same name.

I have thoroughly researched the issue, tried numerous solutions and nothing worked. Any assistance would be great

Definition Table

PK Id

FK CourseId

FK TypeId

FK MethodId

Name

Description

IsActive

spTestSearch

```
USE [Project]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spTestSearch]    Script Date: 2/15/2017 7:39:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:  Riley
-- Create date: 2/15/2017
-- Description: Search Attempt 2
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTestSearch] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Name         NVARCHAR(50),
@CourseIdList           XML,
@TypeIdList             XML,
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM [Definition] ad
         JOIN [Course] c ON ad.CourseId = c.Id
         JOIN [Type] am ON ad.TypeId = am.Id
    WHERE ad.IsActive = 1 AND
    ((ISNULL(@Name, '') = '') OR (ad.Name Like '%'+@Name+'%')) AND 
    ((@CourseIdList IS NULL) OR (ad.CourseId IN
    (       SELECT Id
            FROM dbo.fnIntTableFromXML(@CourseIdList)
     ))) AND
    ((@TypeIdList IS NULL) OR (ad.TypeId IN
    (       SELECT Id
            FROM dbo.fnIntTableFromXML(@TypeIdList)
     )))

END
```

Db.Model.Context.cs

```
public virtual ObjectResult<spTestSearch_Result> spTestSearch(string Name, string courseIdList, string TypeIdList)
{
    var NameParameter = Name != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("Name", Name) :
        new ObjectParameter("Name", typeof(string));

    var CourseIdListParameter = courseIdList != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("CourseIdList", courseIdList) :
        new ObjectParameter("CourseIdList", typeof(string));

    var TypeIdListParameter = TypeIdList != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("TypeIdList", TypeIdList) :
        new ObjectParameter("TypeIdList", typeof(string));


    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<spTestSearch_Result>("spTestSearch", NameParameter, CourseIdListParameter, TypeIdListParameter);
}
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be because you are retrieving all fields of all tables in your stored procedure and it doesn't retrieve a field that matches with a member of the TestSearch_Result object, in this case it would be 'Method'.

Comment: You are exactly right that was the problem! Now I know it is improper to use a ' Select * ' for a stored procedure. Plz give my post an upvote. Your insight is tremendous!